# How to create bytes list in python?

Tags: python, list, serial-port, byte, pyserial

I am facing a challenge to create a bytes list in python. I just want to convert the int list into bytes list as mentioned in expected result. The problem statement is that I want to send the expected output to the serial device connected to the com port and with current output the serial device is not encouraging the '\\' as a separator. Please suggest me the correct way to handle the '\' in a list of bytes.

```
cmdlist = [2, 12, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 7, 42, 101, 85, 18]
    
#Convert CMD list to Hex List
for i in range(len(cmdlist)):
    cmdlist[i] = hex(cmdlist[i])

f_cmdList = ''
#Convert hex CMD list to string List
for i in range(len(cmdlist)):
    f_cmdList += '\\' + (cmdlist[i])

Final_cmdlist = (bytes(f_cmdList,'utf-8'))
print(Final_cmdlist)
```

**Current output**  : b'\\0x2\\0xc\\0x1\\0x1\\0x1\\0x0\\0x0\\0x1\\0x3\\0x7\\0x2a\\0x65\\0x55\\0x12'

**Expected output** : b'\0x2\0xc\0x1\0x1\0x1\0x0\0x0\0x1\0x3\0x7\0x2a\0x65\0x55\0x12'

Thank You !

Comment: Do you have values larger than 127 or why do you do it like that?

Comment: Yes. The values are from  0 to 255 range.

Comment: And your intention was to encode with UTF-8, i.e., encode values 128 to 255 as two bytes each?

Comment: Btw I highly doubt that what you say you expect is really what you expect. A bunch of hex-ish strings separated by zero-bytes? Are you sure?

Comment: It's like if I run above code I will get the output bytes -  `b'\\0x2\\0xc\\0x1\\0x1\\0x1\\0x0\\0x0\\0x1\\0x3\\0x7\\0x2a\\0x65\\0x55\\0x12'`

But I want to create a bytes list where i want only single backslash instead of 2 after each hex number in the bytes frame output - `b'\0x2\0xc\0x1\0x1\0x1\0x0\0x0\0x1\0x3\0x7\0x2a\0x65\0x55\0x12'`

Comment: You already said that in the question, not sure why you repeat it here.

Comment: Sorry for that, But can we do that first of all.

Comment: Yes, we can ...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a list to `bytes` simply by using the `bytes` constructor. Your method is trying to create a string that contains the string representation of a byte array, which won't work when sent to the serial device:

```
>>> cmdlist = [2, 12, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 7, 42, 101, 85, 18]
>>> bytes(cmdlist)
b'\x02\x0c\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x03\x07*eU\x12'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. if you compare the hex values of your output then we can see there garbage data is present or we can say that bytes constructor is not converting the data into hex format as our expected output.

Expected output : b'\0x2\0xc\0x1\0x1\0x1\0x0\0x0\0x1\0x3\0x7\0x2a\0x65\0x55\0x12'

Comment: `bytes` constructor is **not** converting the data into hex. That's only the representation when you print the array on the console. Because `0x65` is also ASCII `e` Python prefers to represent that character as text. It won't affect your serial communication.

Answer (score 0):

[You get what you say you expect](https://tio.run/##jVDBboMwDL37KyztkERlUoCxoko9dap26L6Aooqy0EZiAYV0ol/PnJaVrqdFfpad2H4vbs/u2Jg4be0wlF@fte4cLjGLAgw9fk1ejII4wHmAL/5NUpomFKQ5qL5Vpe/cs63sI0JJCO8gR/g4Jsx9XUHuNSGXeBdGDACeVo35Vtbh6uMNL3pcg@@qxw3FUDUWNWqDtjAHxWtl@ChbiAUgnTHNdE5yjqrn04UAqHaUbq6/ZGwio8I/hJ2z2hz@yzlNndHYrWQ4u9ORhYscYK1NUe@mHfP92amO31oDdnLVc8oEqYSW2B1/aFnidc1iGH4A) if you replace your

```
f_cmdList += '\\' + (cmdlist[i])
```

with this:

```
f_cmdList += '\0' + cmdlist[i][1:]
```

Still not convinced that you really want that, though.

Comment: The comparison is fine but while sending `Final_cmdlist` in ser.write(Final_cmdlist) it will be sent to the device like - `b'\x00x2\x00xc\x00x1\x00x1\x00x1\x00x0\x00x0\x00x1\x00x3\x00x7\x00x2a\x00x65\x00x55\x00x12'` where the device will not encourage extra x0 after backslash in each hex value.

Comment: @Chetan That's just the representation for us humans. The actual string value is identical. Presumably you got that representation by printing it? Print your expected value as well, and you'll see it looks exactly the same.

Comment: I agree with you but if you could run the below code and the way it prints the output is I want.
https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Pzk3Jae4RMFWIZqLM0k9psLACIgtgNgQio1jKtycYypMQGIGEOzkpq7DpQAExGowNQVpiLXmKijKzCvRgNgZbRCr@f8/AA

Comment: So `12` becomes `\x08`? How? I don't see the logic.